# Extract first part of URL

Tags: powershell

I have an URL like so:

`https://www.example.com/oauth/connect/token`

I want to get only `https://www.example.com` and I have tried a bunch of ways to get this but all the ways I have tried require me to hardcode multiple `/`s.

Example:

`$Url.Split('/')[0] + "//" + $url.split('/')[2]`

Is there a way to do this without using the harcoding?

Comment: `$uri = [uri] 'https://www.example.com/oauth/connect/token'; $uri.AbsoluteUri.Replace($uri.AbsolutePath, '')` should do it

Comment: You can also do something like this using replace and regex `'https://www.example.com/oauth/connect/token' -replace '(?<!/)/(?!/)[\S]*'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `[System.Uri]`, to 'cast' the string into an `System.Uri` class.

```
$url = [System.Uri]"https://www.example.com/oauth/connect/token"
```

You can then use the `host` and `scheme` to get the part of the URL you want.

```
$result = $url.Scheme, $url.Host -join "://"
```

You could also remove the `AbsolutePath` from the entire URL.

```
$url = [System.Uri]"https://www.example.com/oauth/connect/token"

$result = $url.AbsoluteUri.Replace($url.AbsolutePath, "")
```

This is the complete list of attributes that the `System.Uri` instance will have:

```
AbsolutePath   : /oauth/connect/token
AbsoluteUri    : https://www.example.com/oauth/connect/token
LocalPath      : /oauth/connect/token
Authority      : www.example.com
HostNameType   : Dns
IsDefaultPort  : True
IsFile         : False
IsLoopback     : False
PathAndQuery   : /oauth/connect/token
Segments       : {/, oauth/, connect/, token}
IsUnc          : False
Host           : www.example.com
Port           : 443
Query          :
Fragment       :
Scheme         : https
OriginalString : https://www.example.com/oauth/connect/token
DnsSafeHost    : www.example.com
IdnHost        : www.example.com
IsAbsoluteUri  : True
UserEscaped    : False
UserInfo       :
```

Comment: I guess there is no going around hardcoding strings to get the scheme and host together.

Comment: @qwerty What you could do is take the `AbsoluteUri` attribute and then remove the `AbsolutePath` attribute from it. It gets rid of the hardcoding and gives you the same result.